# How to make my python script easy portable? or how to compile into binary with all module dependencies?

Tags: python, binary, freebsd

Is there any way to compile python script into binary?
I have one file python script which uses a lot of modules.
What I would like is to have its copy on other machines (freebsd) but without installing all needed modules on every host.

What are possible solutions in such cases?

Comment: possible duplicate of [py2exe - generate single executable file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/112698/py2exe-generate-single-executable-file)

Comment: how can I run exe under freebsd?

Comment: The *answer* to the duplicate question clearly points to **Pyinstaller**, which makes executables for Windows, Linux and OS X.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Programs that can do what you ask for are:

- PyInstaller: http://www.pyinstaller.org/ [Windows, Linux, OS X]
- cx_freeze: http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/ [Windows, Linux]
- py2exe: http://www.py2exe.org/ [Windows]
- py2app: http://svn.pythonmac.org/py2app/py2app/trunk/doc/index.html [os x]

But as mentioned you can also create a Package with Distribute and have the other packages as dependencies. You can then uses `pip` to install that package, and it will install all of the packages. You still need to install Python and pip, though.

Answer (score 3):

[cx_freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/) will append your python scripts to a standalone Python loader and produce a directory containing the program, and shared library dependencies.  You can then copy the resulting distribution to other machines independent of Python or your modules.

```
$ cat hello.py 
print "Hello, World!"
$ ls dist/
datetime.so  _heapq.so  hello  libpython2.6.so.1.0  readline.so
$ cat hello.py 
print "Hello, World!"
$ cxfreeze hello.py 
... <snip> ...
$ ls dist/
datetime.so  _heapq.so  hello  libpython2.6.so.1.0  readline.so
$ ./dist/hello
Hello, World!
```

A better answer may be to create a PIP package that identifies these third modules as dependencies, so installation can be as simple as "pip install mypackage; ./package"

Comment: Does it actually compile to C? I thought that it works like py2exe: Put all the Python files into a .zip and fues it with a small executable that unzips and feeds it to the Python runtime.

Comment: Correct; got this tangled up with the original Python freeze.  The cx-freeze utility concatenates zip-compressed modules to a stub loader.  Not too terribly different from how I achieved the same with MOSREF's compiler.

Comment: // , Does this work if that version of Python isn't installed on the system, though?

Answer (score 2):

Python will also look for `import` modules in the current directory, so you don't have to install them into the python directory. Your distribution file structure might look like:

```
main.py
module1/
    __init__.py, ...
module2/
    __init__.py, ...
```

Where main.py has `import module1, module2`

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to create a Python package from your script. In the end you will be able to do `pip install mypackage` on any host and all the required modules will be downloaded and installed automatically.

[See this question on how to create such a package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155914/how-to-create-a-python-2-x-package-simple-case).