# Create python script that don't depend on modules

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've made a python script that depends of numpy, cv2 and some other modules to run and need to run it on a Linux server where I'm not allowed to install anything.
Is there a way to join all that stuff into a single executable that runs without installing anything?

Comment: That depends. Does the Linux server have Python and pip? Can you create a [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/table/)? Else look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458048/how-to-make-a-python-script-standalone-executable-to-run-without-any-dependency and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4556424/how-to-make-my-python-script-easy-portable-or-how-to-compile-into-binary-with-a

Comment: @Jedi It has python installed, pip I believe it doesn't, I'm not allowed to create a virtualenv.

Comment: You can try to use the method described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12332975/installing-python-module-within-code

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're looking for [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/), which bundles all the modules your script depends on into a single program. It even includes Python itself. There are a few alternatives, some of which are listed [on this page](http://python-guide-pt-br.readthedocs.io/en/latest/shipping/freezing/).

Answer (score 1):

You could create a standalone executable using [Nuitka](http://nuitka.net/pages/overview.html). Assuming you have all required packages on your development machine you can run

```
nuitka --python-version=2.7 --standalone foobar
```

Just make sure you run it with the `standalone` flag and correct python version.