# How to make scripts in the bin folder available to user after installation?

Tags: python, packaging

Suppose my package has the following structure:

```
.
├── LICENSE.txt
├── MANIFEST
├── MANIFEST.in
├── README
├── README.md
├── bin
│   └── myscript.py
├── dist
│   ├── pypack2-0.1.1.tar.gz
│   └── pypack2-0.1.2.tar.gz
├── pypack2
│   ├── Pypack.py
│   └── __init__.py
├── setup.cfg
└── setup.py

4 directories, 14 files
```

So I have made a `myscript.py` file that could be useful for direct use in shell, the question is: How can I make sure that after `pip install pypack`, `myscript.py` will be available to the user, i.e. in their `$PATH`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a python 2.x package - simple case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155914/how-to-create-a-python-2-x-package-simple-case)

Comment: very likely a duplicate of stackoverflow.com/questions/4155914/how-to-create-a-python-2-x-package-simple-case which mentiones the undocumented `py_modules` parameters, but besides that contains a lot of hints already

Comment: @KarlRichter: [`py_modules` is documented](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html?highlight=py_modules#listing-individual-modules). I don't see how to package `bin/script` in the linked question